# Convert Pandas dataframe to a dictionary with first column as key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a Pandas Dataframe :

```
A  ||  B  ||  C
x1    x      [x,y]
x2    a      [b,c,d]
```

and I am trying to make a dictionary to that looks like:

```
{x1: {B : x, c : [x,y]}, x2: {B: a, C:[b,c,d}}
```

I have tried the `to_dict` function but that changes the entire dataframe into a dictionary. I am kind of lost on how to iterate onto the first column and make it the key and the rest of the df a dictionary as the value of that key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = df.set_index("A").to_dict("index")
print(x)
```

Prints:

```py
{'x1': {'B': 'x', 'C': ['x', 'y']}, 'x2': {'B': 'a', 'C': ['b', 'c', 'd']}}
```

Comment: @Rahul open up an interactive interpreter and break it down. There are only two dataframe methods in use. So printing `df.set_index("A")` should provide all of the insight there.

Comment: @Rahul [`.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict) accepts various parameters. One is `orient=` (how do you want to *orient* the output dictionary). There are examples in the documentation.

Comment: Great! The use of `set_index` is the key here. Without it, `to_dict` would use numeric indices, creating another unnecessary level of nesting.